# How do I turn of the Image Preview in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working in an MVC project and when I hover over an image src (or background image) in a .cshtml file it shows a popup of the image.

Is there a way to turn this off?

[image]

I couldn't find any answers on SO. Sorry if it's already been asked.

*EDIT* Visual Studio 2017

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What VS Version?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to determine that the extension HTML Tools by Mads Kristensen was the culprit of the image over. Once disabling the extension my issue was resolved.

I've asked in the Q/A to determine if I can disable that feature individually.

Hopefully this answer will help someone else!